# Eclipse "Add unimplemented methods" method ordering

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has a feature "Add unimplemented methods" that adds the unimplemented methods for a class (such as when implementing an interface).

When Eclipse adds the methods it adds them in alphabetical order. Is there a way to configure Eclipse to add them in the order that they appear in the interface (or abstract class)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be available in eclipse 3.6.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=140971